# Setting Spark cores on cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I am working on a Spark project for school and need to benchmark performance for the number of cores using used. After getting some confusion results, I realized that when I was using the "top" command during execution the CPU usage appeared to be greater than the cores specified. For example, I have set --total-executor-cores 8 and am getting a CPU usage of about 1100% instead of the < 800% I was expecting. The same behavior occurs for different number of cores. This is being run on a 56-core cluster which I believe is likely 7 8-core Xeon CPUs.

I also realized that when I set the cores on my 8-core laptop the CPU usage is bound as expected. I have tried many combinations of setting the number of cores/executors but cannot seem to make sense of it. Even setting local[8] in the Spark config code does not keep the CPU usage under 800%. When I am running this program it is from a local copy of Spark (this is shared school server without a global spark install).

Is there something wrong about how I am running the Spark jobs or something strange with defaults in the local copy of Spark? I am guessing there is something simple I am missing.

**Update:** I tried two synthetic datasets that I created with 10 features and 50k and 100k samples. I noticed that setting local[16] with the 50k dataset the CPU usage is around 1800%, but when I run the same job on the 100k dataset I see a CPU usage of 2500%. What is going on and why cannot I force the number of cores to use?

**Update 2**
I tried a number of different settings when I ran the program but was unable to control the actual CPUs being used. For one of the tests I manually created the master and slaves (start-master.sh/start-slave.sh) and had my job connect to the master. I then used the htop command to view the CPU usage per core on the server and saw some interesting results. When I set the --conf spark.cores.max=1 or 2 I see the expected CPU usage. However, when I increase the cores to 4 or more I see most of the cores getting 20-40% usage and a few cores closer to 90%. Can anyone explain this behavior? I would have expected setting 4 cores would have resulted in mostly empty cores and 4 that were maxed out. I was the only user on the cluster at the time of this test.

The first screenshot shows htop results for 2 cores being used. You can see two cores are maxed out and the rest are at very low usage. The total CPU % being used is 337% which is about right if you take two worked cores and one driver, although I would have thought it would have been under 300%.
[2 cores used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwn6g.png)

The second screenshot shows the exact same thing except I asked for four cores not two. There are about four cores that are at a higher usage rate but the rest of the cores are being used. The total CPU usage is ~1500% which is not correct for four cores.
[4 cores used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk3fE.png)

Comment: how many cores is the driver using?

Comment: I am not completely sure, is there a good way to check or force the number? This could account for some of the difference (although I suspect there are not 10 drivers for a one executor job).